# Different x axis ranges systems Graphs in GLE

Tags: plot

I come up with some problem related to GLE plots. Actually I have three different systems(sys1,sys2 and sys3) in which each one have different x axis ranges, e.g. range of x axis of sys1 (-2:0.2:3), range of x axis of sys2 (0:.5:18) and similarly the same for x axis of sys3 (15:5:40). The y axis values may be same or different. I want to plot all of the three systems in one Graph in the range of 0:0.5:50. The working example is given. Your reply will be highly appreciable.

```
size 22 18 !box

sub mygrids
begin graph
    size 22 18
    nobox
    !title "EbN0db Vs BER with EEP"
    xaxis  min -2 max 40 dticks 1.0 dticks 5.0
    yaxis  min 0.00000003 max 0.5 log 
    xaxis grid lstyle 2 color grey
    yaxis grid lstyle 2 color grey

    !let d1  = 0 from 0 to 10
    !d1 lstyle 0
end graph
end sub

amove 0 0
!@mygrids
set lwidth 0.03
begin graph
    size 22 18 
    nobox
    xaxis  min -2 max 40 dticks 1.0 dticks 5.0
    yaxis  min 0.00000003 max 0.5 log 
    xtitle E_b/N_0[db]
    ytitle BER
    data sys1.txt d1=c1,c2
    d1 lstyle 1 marker fcircle msize 0.3 !color red
    data sys2.txt d2=c1,c2
    d2 lstyle 2 marker circle msize 0.3 !color green
    data sys3.txt d3=c1,c2
    d3 lstyle 3 marker triangle msize 0.3 !color blue

end graph
```

Comment: I've deleted the tag `matlab` and `matlab-figure` since it is not matlab related.

Comment: Yeah, its related to GLE plots but GLE plots was not found in the list.